# .NET Framework 4.8 webforms JWT login

Tags: c#, asp.net, jwt, webforms, .net-4.8

I'm having trouble to implement login function. User logs in fine and creates JWT token but is unable to maintain the logged in state after page refresh or redirect to another page. How could I implement it without using WebApi? There's clearly lack of knowledge and information on my end because couldn't find anything that'd work. (Used to use .net core before and it was a breeze compared to this)

Appreciate any help. :)

Current code fragments:

```
public class JwtAuthentication
    {
        private readonly string _issuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Issuer"];
        private readonly string _audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Audience"];
        private static readonly string _secret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecretKey"];

        public void ConfigureJwtAuthentication(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var keyByteArray = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(_secret);
            var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(keyByteArray);

            var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = _issuer,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = _audience,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };

            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters
            });
        }

        public static string GenerateJwtToken(string email)
        {
            var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email)
            };

            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
                    new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_secret)),
                    SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

            return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
        }
    }
```

Simple login to check if it works:

```
public void LoginUser(TextBox emailText, TextBox passwordText, Label errorMessage)
        {
            string email = emailText.Text;
            string password = passwordText.Text;

            password = InOutUtils.CalculateHash(email, password);

            User user = _repo.GetUserByEmail(email);

            if (email == user.Email && password == user.Password)
            {
                string token = JwtAuthentication.GenerateJwtToken(email);
                _response.AppendCookie(new HttpCookie("jwt", token));

                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email)}, "jwt");

                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email));

                var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

                HttpContext.Current.User = principal;

                _response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                errorMessage.Text = "Error";
            }
        }
```

Tried using Owin startup class and other ways to configure JWT authentication but they didn't seem to work or it required additional functionality to properly work, not sure what to do after this.

Comment: You need to send a token with each request so you do not need to login.  See : https://frontegg.com/blog/jwt-authentication

Comment: Thank you for setting me on the right path! :)